# setAnimation changed since Lottie 3.0 update?

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

The AirBNB's README.md for Lottie IOS updated. setAnimation not in Readme, and not registering in swift dropdown list of selectors for updated version 3.0.0 Has anyone experienced this issue? Lottie cocoapod is successfully installed.

README.md
trial and error
restart

```
@IBOutlet private var animationView: AnimationView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startAnimation()

}

func startAnimation() {

    animationView.setAnimation(named: "spineffectloader")
    animationView.play()

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In swift, you need to update code as follow to register animation:

```
animationView.animation = Animation.named("spineffectloader")
```

To start animation use following code:

```
animationView.play { (finished) in
    /// Animation finished
}
```

Comment: Any hint for objective-C code for the same. I'm unable to find anything under AnimationView property or method in the codehint.